# struct.unpack of serial stream

Tags: python

I have successfully read a serial stream of 12 bytes into a byte array.

The data format of the stream is as follows:

```
1 STX 0x02
2 Data1_LL
3 Data1_LH
4 Data1_HL
5 Data1_HH
6 Data2_LL
7 Data2_LH
8 Data2_HL
9 Data2_HH
10 Data3_L
11 Data3_H
12 ETX 0x03
```

I am trying to unpack this using the following:

```
data = uart.read(32)  # read up to 32 bytes
data = list(data)
buffer += data

while buffer and buffer[0] != "\x02":  # first byte should be 0x02
    buffer.pop(0)

...

frame = struct.unpack('<BiihB', bytes(buffer[0:]))
fixed1, data1, data2, data3, fixed2 = frame
```

I believe I have the < correct as the data is little endian.

However this is giving the error:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 12
```

The string appears to be of the format '\x00', '\x08', '\x00', '\x00' etc which is giving a length of 96.

How can I convert this into the required format, and does the struct unpack look OK for the data format?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: What data type is `buffer`? You don't show that in your code. You need to pass `unpack()` a string, not a list.

Comment: if you have to decode 12 bytes then you should use `buffer[0:12]` - and you should run it in loop to work with `[0:12]`, next with `[12:24]`, etc.`96/12` gives 8 frames.